# Why the controller method is running twice?

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following code in my RegisterController:

```
    public function register(RegisterRequest $request)
    {
        $userExists = User::whereEmail($request->get('email'))
            ->orWhere('nickname', $request->get('nickname'))
            ->first();

        \Log::info('User exists before', [$userExists]);
        if ($userExists) {
            \Log::info('User exists after', [$userExists]);

            return $this->response->withErrors([
                'message' => 'Email or nickname already exists'
            ])->build();
        }

        $user = new User();
        $user->email = $request->get('email');
        $user->nickname = $request->get('nickname');
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->get('password'));
        $user->first_name = $request->get('first_name');
        $user->last_name = $request->get('last_name');
        $user->save();


        return $this->response->build(
            [
                'user' => new UserResource($user),
                'access_token' => $user->createToken('web')->plainTextToken
            ]
        );
    }
```

And when I send a request to the `/register` route, I have the following logs in my Laravel.log file:

```
[2021-02-26 10:35:26] testing.INFO: User exists before [null] 
[2021-02-26 10:35:26] testing.INFO: User exists before [{"App\\Models\\User":{"id":1,"inviter_id":null,"first_name":"Jennyfer","last_name":"Howe","nickname":"kolson","email":"cauer@langosh.net","email_verified_at":null,"is_verified":0,"is_banned":0,"is_2fa_enabled":0,"country":null,"city":null,"ga_hash":null,"created_at":"2021-02-26T10:35:26.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-02-26T10:35:26.000000Z"}}] 
[2021-02-26 10:35:26] testing.INFO: User exists after [{"App\\Models\\User":{"id":1,"inviter_id":null,"first_name":"Jennyfer","last_name":"Howe","nickname":"kolson","email":"cauer@langosh.net","email_verified_at":null,"is_verified":0,"is_banned":0,"is_2fa_enabled":0,"country":null,"city":null,"ga_hash":null,"created_at":"2021-02-26T10:35:26.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-02-26T10:35:26.000000Z"}}]
```

Idk what's wrong with this code, but it doesn't work as expected. The most strange thing here is  that I don't have the second string of "User exists after".

Just for information:

- The Nginx log says that I have only 1 request to the route.
- I'm using Laravel Sanctum for authentication

I already spent 2 hours to get any info about this issue and I have no idea what's wrong here

Comment: "_The most strange thing here is that I don't have the second string of "User exists after"._" It's right there in your code: `\Log::info('User exists after', [$userExists]);`

Comment: @brombeer oh, right. But the rest of the question is valid

Comment: how are you sending the request - by accessing the url directly in a browser? What middleware is applied to the route?

Comment: @JamesClarkDeveloper I found a bug, the bug was in my response's middleware, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Ohhh, I made a mistake in my Response's middleware. I'm using it to convert any of `Accept` header to `application/json` to send json-only responses.

So I was running `$next($request)` twice in my middleware:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request->headers->set('Accept', 'application/json');

        $response = $next($request);

        if (!$response instanceof JsonResponse) {
            $response = $this->responseFactory->json(
                $response->content(),
                $response->status(),
                $response->headers->all()
            );
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

So I changed the last line to `return $response` and now it works as expected.

I would like to leave this question for the feature to save other developers' time.